# Fire event on binding values to dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to manipulate the values during the bind of those to the `select`. Which of the event can pass the binding value as parameter and return the same with a added property or fetch the option direct and return with adding a property?

Something like this,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserId, Model.UserList, "Select Name", new { @class = "target", @id = "ddlNames" })

$( ".target" ).xxx(function() {
  //Fetch the options here and add a property (selected="selected")
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) with [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains) without using any loop like,

```
$(function() { // just use code in document ready
    $(".target option:contains(Option-Value)").attr('selected','selected');
});
```

Snippet,

```js
$(function() { // just use code in document ready
  $(".target option:contains(Option 4)").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="target">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can. Iterate over options.

```
// initially set options to select.
$( ".target" ).xxx(function() {
  $("select option").each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == "something")
    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
 });
});
```

Remember that you can select only one option at a time. So make sure you know the option which you want to select.

Comment: Yes, but do i have any option to do it while binding the list of values?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. You can make any one of them selected. Would be better if you show how you binding them.

Comment: @iamCR Looks like that is ASP code and I am not much well with its syntax . Sorry.